# converting small as3 code to as2

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

client got a project back from another programmer who wrote it in as2 (i don't know why) I just need to add in some tracking code for button clicks to the fla file.  here's the code that's currently in as3 that needs to go to as2:

```
    var trackingURL:String = "";

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();    

// TODO: Insert Event-specific fields below
variables.value1 = "";
variables.value2 = "";  

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(trackingURL + "?cacheKiller=" + (new Date()).getTime());
request.data = variables;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var trackingURL = "";

var trackInfo = new LoadVars();

trackInfo.value1 = "";
trackInfo.value2 = "";

var myDate = new Date();
trackInfo.send(trackingURL + "?cacheKiller=" + (myDate.UTC), "_self", "POST");
```

You obviously need to populate trackingURL, value1 and value2

Comment: worked like a charm thanks!  dont' know why I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: @Kast I'm glad! You may wish to mark this as the correct answer if your issue is now resolved.